# am not able to remove my list-style in css

Tags: html, css

I have a nav menu that contain several list items. However, I have not been successful at removing the list item styling using CSS.

Here is my code so far:

```css
.links {
    overflow:auto;
}
    
.lnk {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#111111;
}

.lnk li {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul class="lnk">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>        
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Unfortunately, none of what I'm trying is working for me. I don't know what else to do. None of my CSS code is even working. They are external files and I have linked them to my page, but they are still not working. Please, I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um I think it might work like this?

```
.links {
     overflow:auto;
}
.lnk {
     list-style:none;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     background-color:#111;
}

li .lnk{
       float:left;
}
```

I don't know your HTML code so I don't know the problem. Can you post that too? And please explain what your problem is clearer. Oh and I also organized it. I think the problem is that you put `.lnk lk` instead of `li .lnk`. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This will helpful for you

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<p>Some text goes here</p>
</div>
css part:
div#wrapper ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
div#wrapper p {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i really appreciate your help